# Less specific jQuery UI Autocomplete that accepts un-ordered terms

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hello looking for assistance on how I can make my code less specific when performing a search. Right now it will only produce results if what the user types is exactly how it is stored. So if the search term is in all caps the user must type it in all caps ect... I did use the toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() and that helps to allow a word to be in caps or lower but still the search is too specific.

What I want is if say I have Apple and Banana, if I type the letter 'a' or 'A' it should show both results in the autocomplete. I am open to refactoring my code but still want it to work the same. The search is actually used to navigate to different URL's. So if you type 'Google' and click a button it will open a new tab and go to Googles home page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({url:"123.123.1.12:3000/index",
  success: function(data) {
     // console.log(data);

       $("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
         minLength: 1,
         source: function(req, resp) {
           var q = req.term;
           var myResponse = [];

           $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, item) {

             if (item.value.indexOf(q) === 0 ) {
               //TODO: THIS MIGHT CAUSE BUGS
               item.value = item.value + ' ' + item.env;
               myResponse.push(item);
             }
             // console.log(item.value);
           });

           resp(myResponse);
         }, //end of source

         select: function(event, ui) {

           $('#goBtn').one("click", function(){

             if ($('#appsearch').val() === ""){
               console.log('search is empty');
             } else

             window.open(ui.item.url);
             $('#appsearch').val('');
             $('#alertText').text('');

           });
         }

       }); //end of $("input.autocomplete").autocomplete
   }, //end of success
 }); //end of ajax
});
```

Comment: You can use something like `item.value.indexOf(q) >= 0` this will look for for `q` in any part of the item.

Comment: I would also set everything to 1 case: `item.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Thank you so much, just added the item.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) and it works perfectly. Can't believe how simple that was......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide an example of the data, it's hard to provide a complete answer. Consider this basic example:

```js
$(function() {
  var projects = [{
      value: "jquery",
      label: "jQuery",
      desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
      icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
    },
    {
      value: "jquery-ui",
      label: "jQuery UI",
      desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
      icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
    },
    {
      value: "sizzlejs",
      label: "Sizzle JS",
      desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
      icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
    }
  ];

  $("#project").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var q = req.term;
      var results = [];
      $.each(projects, function(k, item) {
        var itm = item.label.toLowerCase();
        if (itm.indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
          results.push(item);
        }
      });
      resp(results);
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
      $("#project-description").html(ui.item.desc);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#project-label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#project-description {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="project-label">Select a project:</div>
<input id="project">
<p id="project-description"></p>
```

If you need to adjust or change the value, you can. I would suggest doing so after you have the results. Remember that your result must be an array. It can contain objects that have `{ label, value }` and further more indexes. Those two indexes must be in there somewhere.

Comment: For data I am using MongoDB and im sending the data to my route using node.js. But just changing that one line of code to 
if(item.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) >= 0) did the trick!